# are these 2 matrices equals?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question:
Suppose that the matrices A and C satisfy the equations Ax = b and Cx = b with the same set of solutions x for every b. Can we
conclude that A = C?

I would like to know if you think that this answer is good enough :

1. Ax = Cx
2. Ax - Cx = 0
3. (A-C)x = 0
4. (A -C)x*x^(-1) = 0
5. (A -C)In = 0
6. A = C

Thanks ;)

Comment: How do you define the inverse of the  vector $x?$

Comment: yeah that's a good question. I obviously cannot do that.

Comment: ahhh! I see! if I stop at the third step and I say that there are two solutions, x= 0 and A=C it would be correct?

Comment: No you have e.g. $
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
$ and both factors are non-zero.

Comment: indeed... so I don't see how to proceed then. Have you got a hint plz?

Comment: Sorry,  I do not have a proof, I just pointed out the weaknesses in your arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument can be rescued. Consider two vectors $x_1,x_2$. By assumption
$$A x_1=C x_1$$
$$A x_2=C x_2$$
so
$$A [x_1,x_2]=[A x_1, A x_2]=[C x_1, C x_2]=C [x_1, x_2]$$
Now, take $N$ linearly independent vectors and form the square invertible matrix $x=[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$ (i.e. $x$ has $x_1$ as its first column, $x_2$ as its second column, etc.). You still have $Ax=Cx$, and now your step 4 becomes possible.

Comment: wow! I think I understand what are you saying. I mean my english is not the best one. But if I'm right you say that I can take x_n (lin.indep) vectors and we suppose that each of them validate the assumption. Then I make an inversible square matrix with them and indeed if its a matrix step 4 becomes possible. right?

Comment: @Moleson Exactly

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the standard basis, so that $Ae_i = y_i$ is the i$^{\text{th}}$ column of $A$.  By your assumption, we know that $e_i$ is a solution to $Cx=y_i$, so $Ce_i=y_i$.  Therefore $A$ and $C$ have the same columns, ie. they are equal.